# Oracle 19c - Cannot unplug PDB cloned from dblink

Tags: oracle

I would like to unplug a pdb that I've created from a clone through a db link this way:

```
create pluggable database VMPDBD from REMOTEPDB@remote_dblink;
```

The clone is achieved correctly and I can open it without trouble and use it.

But from this clone, I would like to unplug it into a pdb file:

```
alter pluggable database VMPDBD unplug into '/home/oracle/vmpdbd.pdb';
```

The unplug is aborted after a few seconds with an ORA-01426 (numberic overflow).

What could be the source of this error? Where should I check for a log file or table containing some information about this ORA-01426?

**UPDATE 1:**

Here is the alert log generated:

> 2021-06-23T06:00:30.987449+00:00
> ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE VMPDBD_UNPLUG UNPLUG INTO '/home/oracle/VMPDBD_UNPLUG.pdb'
> ORA-65011 signalled during: ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE VMPDBD_UNPLUG UNPLUG INTO '/home/oracle/VMPDBD_UNPLUG.pdb'...
> 2021-06-23T06:00:45.741164+00:00
> ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE VMPDBD UNPLUG INTO '/home/oracle/VMPDBD_UNPLUG.pdb'
> Errors in file /opt/oracle/diag/rdbms/dockcdb/DOCKCDB/trace/DOCKCDB_ora_16155.trc  (incident=41564) (PDBNAME=VMPDBDOTNPLUG):
> ORA-00700: soft internal error, arguments: [sga_min_size], [1610612736], [805306368], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
> (4):Incident details in: /opt/oracle/diag/rdbms/dockcdb/DOCKCDB/incident/incdir_41564/DOCKCDB_ora_16155_i41564.trc
> 2021-06-23T06:00:48.119462+00:00
> Dumping diagnostic data in directory=[cdmp_20210623060048], requested by (instance=1, osid=16155), summary=[incident=41564].
> 2021-06-23T06:00:48.139934+00:00
> VMPDBD(4):Autotune of undo retention is turned on.
> 2021-06-23T06:00:48.370022+00:00
> VMPDBD(4):Endian type of dictionary set to little
> VMPDBD(4):Undo initialization recovery: err:0 start: 166573287 end: 166573290 diff: 3 ms (0.0 seconds)
> VMPDBD(4):[16155] Successfully onlined Undo Tablespace 2.
> VMPDBD(4):Undo initialization online undo segments: err:0 start: 166573290 end: 166573353 diff: 63 ms (0.1 seconds)
> VMPDBD(4):Undo initialization finished serial:0 start:166573287 end:166573358 diff:71 ms (0.1 seconds)
> VMPDBD(4):Database Characterset for VMPDBD is AL32UTF8
> 2021-06-23T06:00:51.189186+00:00
> VMPDBD(4):JIT: pid 16155 requesting stop
> VMPDBD(4):Buffer Cache flush started: 4
> VMPDBD(4):Buffer Cache flush finished: 4
> ORA-1426 signalled during: ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE VMPDBD UNPLUG INTO '/home/oracle/VMPDBD_UNPLUG.pdb'...
> 2021-06-23T06:00:30.987449+00:00
> ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE VMPDBD_UNPLUG UNPLUG INTO '/home/oracle/VMPDBD_UNPLUG.pdb'
> ORA-65011 signalled during: ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE VMPDBD_UNPLUG UNPLUG INTO '/home/oracle/VMPDBD_UNPLUG.pdb'...
> 2021-06-23T06:00:45.741164+00:00
> ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE VMPDBD UNPLUG INTO '/home/oracle/VMPDBD_UNPLUG.pdb'
> Errors in file /opt/oracle/diag/rdbms/dockcdb/DOCKCDB/trace/DOCKCDB_ora_16155.trc  (incident=41564) (PDBNAME=VMPDBDOTNPLUG):
> ORA-00700: soft internal error, arguments: [sga_min_size], [1610612736], [805306368], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
> (4):Incident details in: /opt/oracle/diag/rdbms/dockcdb/DOCKCDB/incident/incdir_41564/DOCKCDB_ora_16155_i41564.trc
> 2021-06-23T06:00:48.119462+00:00
> Dumping diagnostic data in directory=[cdmp_20210623060048], requested by (instance=1, osid=16155), summary=[incident=41564].
> 2021-06-23T06:00:48.139934+00:00
> VMPDBD(4):Autotune of undo retention is turned on.
> 2021-06-23T06:00:48.370022+00:00
> VMPDBD(4):Endian type of dictionary set to little
> VMPDBD(4):Undo initialization recovery: err:0 start: 166573287 end: 166573290 diff: 3 ms (0.0 seconds)
> VMPDBD(4):[16155] Successfully onlined Undo Tablespace 2.
> VMPDBD(4):Undo initialization online undo segments: err:0 start: 166573290 end: 166573353 diff: 63 ms (0.1 seconds)
> VMPDBD(4):Undo initialization finished serial:0 start:166573287 end:166573358 diff:71 ms (0.1 seconds)
> VMPDBD(4):Database Characterset for VMPDBD is AL32UTF8
> 2021-06-23T06:00:51.189186+00:00
> VMPDBD(4):JIT: pid 16155 requesting stop
> VMPDBD(4):Buffer Cache flush started: 4
> VMPDBD(4):Buffer Cache flush finished: 4
> ORA-1426 signalled during: ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE VMPDBD UNPLUG INTO '/home/oracle/VMPDBD_UNPLUG.pdb'...

And part of the trc file:

> *** 2021-06-23T06:00:45.818040+00:00
> ORA-00700: soft internal error, arguments: [sga_min_size], [1610612736], [805306368], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
>
> *** 2021-06-23T06:00:45.818057+00:00 [TOC00001-END]
>
> *** 2021-06-23T06:00:45.818718+00:00 [TOC00002]
>
> *** 2021-06-23T06:00:45.818746+00:00
> ========= Dump for incident 41564 (ORA 700 [sga_min_size]) ========
>
> *** 2021-06-23T06:00:45.818770+00:00 [TOC00003]
>
> *** 2021-06-23T06:00:45.818796+00:00
> ----- Beginning of Customized Incident Dump(s) -----
>
> *** 2021-06-23T06:00:45.818826+00:00
>
> *** 2021-06-23T06:00:45.818842+00:00                                    Parameter value is too big for current SGA configuration, should be <=
> 805306368, setting it to 0

What's strange is that the sga_min_size is setted to 0 and not 1610612736 in the pdb:

> sga_max_size  1610612736  1536M   0

> sga_min_size  0   0   0

> sga_target    0   0   0

I tried to change the sga_max_size to 805306368, but still the same issue

**UPDATE 2:**

```
select con_id, name, value from v$system_parameter where name like  'sga%'  order by con_id;
```

Give the result:

> 0 sga_max_size    1610612736

> 4 sga_target  0

> 4 sga_min_size    0

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you check the alert logs for more details on this error

Comment: Also try the same with .xml i.e. creating PDB using xml(metdata).

Comment: I tried with an xml unplug and it's the same error. I will update the question with the log

Comment: I am able to unplug the PDB created using DB link . Please check that PDB while unplugging is in mounted state.

Comment: the pdb is in mounted state, otherwise Oracle complains that it should be it that state

Comment: What is the current SGA_MAX_SIZE in the pdb and can you try to set to 0 and the restart the PDB. Share output of below query: `select con_id, name, value from v$system_parameter where name like 
'sga%' 
order by con_id;`